# How to scroll through mysql database in java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to scroll over all the contents of a database. How do I properly do this:

```
conc conclass = new conc();
        Connection conn = conclass.dbConnect();
        try{


       Statement statement=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        String sql;
        rs=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM q_table");

        if(rs.next()){
        String yo=rs.getString("Question");
        jTextArea1.setText(yo);
        }





        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

And here's my class for connecting to the database:

```
 public Connection dbConnect() {
    try {
        String db_connect_string="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/questions";
        String db_userid="root";
        String db_password="1234";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);


        return conn;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? It loads the first record when I click on the scroll button. But when I click it again. It doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: where is scroll button. BTW, most likely DB Connection is closed.

Comment: The first block of code is inside the jButtonActionPerformed event. I think the problem is that the connection is renewed everytime I click on the button that's why I always see the same result. My problem is where will I put the codes that initialize the connection if its not supposed to be in the button event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the `Resultset` open. For every click on the button, you must call `rs.next()` once. After that, a new row will copied into the `ResultSet`.

Comment: I would advice against keeping ResultSet open for any longer period of time. You might get away with it in this case, but it's wrong by principle to keep ResultSet open waiting for user operation. Read the data to memory when you start, iterated over the data from there.

Comment: @Zds: Agreed; I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 4):

To collect *all* results from table (I assume you mean the table rather than the whole database):

```
while(rs.next()) {
   String yo=rs.getString("Question");
   // add 'yo' to a list or similar...
}
```

You need to iterate across your `ResultSet`. The `ResultSet` scrolls over each row returned from the database in sequence. See [this example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/GetRsData.html) for more details.